# (EXIM) ACL for only allowing internal domain to send to internal group alias

Tags: exim, access-control-list, alias

I'm trying to create an ACL rule that will only allow internal users/white listed users to send to particular group aliases such as all@ or office2@

I know I need something similar to:

```
deny       log_message =  $sender_address is not permitted to send to myprotecteddomain.com my2protecteddomain.com
           domains     = myprotecteddomain.com : my2protecteddomain.com
           ! senders   = *myowndomain.com
```

But possibly using an external file with white-listed addresses in, I'm not that good at Exim ACLs!

Answer (score 1):

If you need this only for local users then I think you should not use `sender` because it can be falsified without any trouble - instead you should configure SMTP [auth](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-smtp_authentication.html) (`begin authenticators` section) and next you can use something like this:

```
deny  recipients   = lsearch*@;/etc/exim/protected-recipients
      !authenticated = *
      message      = Sending denied - protected list - not authenticated - returned to sender
      log_message  = PROTECTED - sending denied not - authenticated - - logged to file

deny  recipients   = lsearch*@;/etc/exim/protected-recipients
      condition    = ${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/exim/allowed-users}{no}{yes}}
      message      = Sending denied - protected list - no access - returned to sender
      log_message  = PROTECTED - sending denied - no access - logged to file
```

For `recipients` I use `lsearch*@;` so you can use both full email addresses and wilcarded like this:

```
protected-user@general.domain
*@protected-domain
```

For authenticated users you need just list it names line by line (note `yes` and `no` order in lookup).

If you need remote users too, then you can add:

```
accept  recipients   = lsearch*@;/etc/exim/protected-recipients
    !sender_domains = +local_domains
    condition    = ${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/exim/allowed-users}{yes}{no}}
```

before first deny and list addresses one per line.

Comment: interesting, this sounds like what I need :-) I'll give this a try once I get some time!